# Discord JS TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I'm creating an event that checks a monogodatabase on a set interval to see if they're any expired keys and then to remove a role from that member.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const { Discord, GuildMemberRoleManager, GuildMember, Guild, Client, Message } = require("discord.js");
const { Database } = require("../../Structures/config.json");
const { count, key } = require("../../Structures/Schemas/keys");
const keys = require('../../Structures/Schemas/keys');

module.exports = {
    name: "ready",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    /**
     * @param {Message} oldMessage
    * @param {GuildMemberRoleManager} 
    * @param {GuildMember} member
    * @param {Guild} guild
    * @param {Client} client
    */
    async execute(client, member, guild) {
        setInterval(() => {
                keys.count({ redeemed: true }, async function( err, results ){
                console.log(results)
                console.log("Number of keys:", results);
                const counts = results;
                const keyfind = await keys.findOne({ redeemed: true });
                    for(let i = 0; i < counts; i++){
                        keys.findOne({ redeemed: true }, 'redeemedAt expiryAt userid', async function (err, keys){
                            if (err) return handleError(err);
                            const currentTime = new Date(Date.now()) 
                            const expirationDate = keys.expiryAt;
                            const timeout = currentTime - expirationDate;
                            const role = guild.roles.cache.get('924064535663480922');
                            const member = await guild.members.fetch(keys.userid);
                            console.log(timeout)
                            if (timeout < -1){
                                await keys.then(keyfind.delete());
                                member.roles.remove(role);
                                
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
                
            }, 3500); 
}
}
```

I keep getting this error whenever the event runs
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's quite hard to give you a conclusive answer with the details you provided.

We know that you are trying to access something that's undefined. Are you sure `guild` is properly passed to your function and have you checked if your fetching of `member` works properly?

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

This is due to newer discord js version require you to use .find and not .get.

Here's what your code should be:

```js
    const role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '924064535663480922');
```

Comment: A predicate function is not an argument you can pass to `Collection.get()`.